# NodeJS, Express and Forever: app going to sleep

Tags: node.js, express, cron

I have an Express website, written in nodeJS, which appears to be going to sleep despite the fact that I'm running it via forever.

Specifically, I have an app.js module which exports two instances (I'm not showing the definition of the app object as it's rather long -- it just sets up the environment in which the express server runs):

```
var updaters = new CronJobManager( );

// hourly update just to show we're working
updaters.add( 'hourly update', '0 0 * * * *', function() {
    winston.info( 'executing hourly update...' )
} );

updaters.add( 'daily update', '0 0 0 * * *', function() {
    winston.info( 'executing daily update...' )
    dailyUpdate( );
} );

module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.updaters = updaters;
```

The CronJobManager instance creates two cron jobs, one of which should be called daily and one of which should be called hourly. dailyUpdate() is a function defined in app.js which updates values in a number of objects.

I invoke this in bin/www as follows (this is using a basic Express4 file layout):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('XmasLights');
var winston = require('../logger.js');
var app = require('../app').app;
var updaters = require('../app').updaters;

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

winston.info('started webserver');

updaters.start('hourly update');
updaters.start('daily update');

winston.info('started updaters');
```

Everything works properly, but if the website isn't accessed for long enough, the app appears to go to sleep, and the cronjob callbacks don't get called. However, as soon as the site is accessed, they do get called.

I thought that forever prevented express apps from going to sleep, but apparently that's not correct. Or I'm missing something.

How do I keep the CronJobManager instance running? Do I need to run it in a separate process or something? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Does the app goes to sleep?  Or does the computer it's hosted on go to sleep?

Comment: Good question. It's running on a raspberry pi 2. So far as I can determine or find via google, pis never go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an "answer", but it's really more of a workaround.

I was able to keep the express app running by setting up a keep-alive cronjob which executed every 10 minutes.

Without that workaround, the app goes into some kind of waiting mode, even though it's still running so far as forever is concerned. It can be "woken up" by simply accessing the website, at which point the pending cronjobs run. Unfortunately, that's not particularly useful when you have cronjobs that are supposed to run at a particular time.